# Эмуляция событий мыши на телефоне

Tags: javascript

Пишу вэб приложение на javascript которое должно быть кросплатформенным, но столкнулся с проблемой при работе с сайтом на телефоне не работают такие события как например onmousedown или onmouseover и прочие, есть ли какое то решение в данном случае, мне нужно реализовать функцию drag n drop, которая на компьютере работает а на телефоне нет.

пока вывожу только координаты на экран но почему то при событии touchmove перезагружается страница в браузере на андроид

```
function test(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var td = document.querySelector('.todo_list ');
            td.innerText = e.touches[0].clientX;
        }
        document.addEventListener('touchstart', test, false);
        document.addEventListener('touchmove', test, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

На сенсорных устройствах срабатывают события touch: touchstart, touchend, touchmove... Вся информация в документации [Тач-события](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Touch_events)

Comment: то есть правильно я понимаю что придется для сенсорных писать отдельные функции?=(

Comment: Нет, только параметры события получать немного другим способом. Главное получить координаты и target. Остально не отличается

Comment: Вроде относительно разобрался но немогу понять почему то при touchmove на андроиде браузер перезагружается (код добавил в основной вопрос)

Comment: @Чайник свайп влево/вправо вызывает переход браузера вперед/назад. Может в этом дело?

Answer (score 0):

`onmousedown` для телефонов это `ontouchstart`, а `onmouseup` - `ontouchend`